# Is there a setting in Android Studio to set `src` directory when the .kt file few folder down?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Sample folder structures:

```
.
└── root/
    ├── app/
    │   ├── function
    │   ├── screen/
    │   │   ├── main_screen.kt
    │   │   └── second_screen.kt
    │   └── main.kt
    └── src/
        ├── one
        ├── two
        ├── three
        └── values/
            ├── strings.xml
            └── colors.xml

Currently I have something like this, where strings.xml and colors.xml include some srcs strings.
```

I tried to use those configs in `main_screen.kt` by calling `R.strings.StringName` but got error message said "StringName" is not defined. At the same time, i tried to write same thing in `main.kt` and it works. I believe it's Android folder structures issue. Anyone can point me to correct way how I suppose to fix it?